# Why don't airbus aircraft have raked wingtips?

Tags: winglets, wing-tip-vortex

Most airbus aircraft have sharkfin winglets or blended winglets. Why is it that none of them have raked wingtips like the 777-300ER?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Boeing holds a number of patents related to raked wingtips, like [US5039032 A High taper wing tip extension](https://www.google.com/patents/US5039032) and [US6089502 A Blunt-leading-edge raked wingtips](https://www.google.com/patents/US6089502), among others.

Comment: The first of those two patents is expired; the second will expire about a year from now.